# How to add arguments to StartLayout for Microsoft Chromium Edge tile when it doesn't accept Desktop Link tile?

Tags: microsoft-edge, chromium, startmenu

Trying to setup a multi-app Provisional Package with a browser in Kiosk mode. Seemingly Microsoft Edge Dev Start tile has to use DesktopApplicationID as DesktopApplicationLinkPath to Edge gets the tile ignored. No such issue with Chrome as it is not a Microsoft or UWP app.

[image: Kiosk]

Couldn't find the XML XSD schema, only this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/start-layout-xml-desktop#layoutmodification-xml

How to add arguments to Microsoft Edge Dev for a Start tile?

First used the Kiosk Browser, but it doesn't accept non-URL URIs. Switched to Chrome and launched it with "kiosk" argument. Heard about Edge using Chromium. Same argument worked, but not as a Start tile.

The last start:DesktopApplicationTile won't show up:

```html
<StartLayout>
    <LayoutModificationTemplate xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout" Version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification">
          <LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" FullScreenStart="1" />
          <DefaultLayoutOverride>
            <StartLayoutCollection>
              <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6">
                <start:Group Name="Homepage">
                  <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Chrome Kiosk.lnk" />
                  <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Edge Kiosk.lnk" />
                </start:Group>
...
```

Comment: Since the edge chromium is still in a development phase, someting works not properly is expected. Searching for information in official site, there is only the content of the current edge https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/lock-down-windows-10-to-specific-apps I suggest that maybe you could send the feedback about the specific feature so that it could help to make this product better.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Start screen, make sure you are using the Microsoft Edge Dev browser instead of using Microsoft Edge browser.

According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/customize-and-export-start-layout), I have tried to export the customize Start with Microsoft Edge, Microsoft chromium Edge and Chrome browser. The layout as below:

```
    <start:Group Name="">
      <start:Tile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" AppUserModelID="windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy!microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel" />
      <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome.lnk" />
      <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="2" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Edge Dev.lnk" />
      <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="4" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Edge Canary.lnk" />
      <start:Tile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="2" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge" />
    </start:Group>
```

It seems that the Microsoft Edge uses the AppUserModelID property and Microsoft chromium Edge (Microsoft Edge Dev and Microsoft Edge Dev) using the DesktopApplicationLinkPath property.

Please navigate to the start menu folder ("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs") and check the browser name, make sure the StartLayout XML are using the same name.

Besides, please refer the [Set up a multi-app kiosk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/lock-down-windows-10-to-specific-apps#apply-ppkg), make sure you have allowed these app to run on the kiosk device.

Finally, **please make sure these apps are installed for users, because, if an app is not installed for the user, but is included in the Start layout XML, the app will not be shown on the Start screen.**